# Find list of id's which have another column change values multiple times

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataframe new_df which has a list of customer id's, dates, and a customer segment for each day. Customer segment can take multiple values. I am looking to identify a list of customers whose segment has changed more than twice in the past 15 days.

Currently, I am using the following to check how many times each segment appears for each customer id.

```
segment_count = new_df.groupby(new_df['customer_id'].ne(new_df['customer_id'].shift()).cumsum())['segment'].value_counts()
```

My thinking is if a customer has more than 2 segments which have a count of >1, then they must have migrated from one segment to another at least twice. 2 sample customers may look like this:

```
|customer_id|day|segment|
|-----------|---|-------|
|12345|'2021-01-01'|G|
|12345|'2021-01-02'|G|
|12345|'2021-01-03'|M|
|12345|'2021-01-04'|G|
|12345|'2021-01-05'|M|
|12345|'2021-01-06'|M|
|6789|'2021-01-01'|G|
|6789|'2021-01-02'|G|
|6789|'2021-01-03'|G|
|6789|'2021-01-04'|G|
|6789|'2021-01-05'|G|
|6789|'2021-01-06'|M|
```

As an output, I would want to return the following:

| customer_id | migration_count |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 3 |
| 6789 | 1 |

Anyone have any advice on best way to tackle this or if there are any built in functions I can use to simplify?Thanks!

Comment: provide the dataframe generation as code so we can paste it in to our IDE's

Comment: Where does the "last 15 days" limitation affect the results?

Comment: @gold_cy I changed the format of the sample df to code from table.

Comment: @Aryerez the sample df i have only shows last 6 days, however the full df has 15 day history for 5M customers. I shortened for simplicity of the post. All I am after is identifying customers whose segment changes more than twice in prior X days, as this segment should be fairly stable and only change at most once in that short time frame